# java socket outgoing router trouble

Tags: java, sockets, routes

I'm doing some work creating basic server/client applications using java through the internet. I found some code for a server/client app on the net and ran it using localhost as the host, and that functions as it should with no problems. so as far as i can tell there's no problem with the code

I have port forwarding enabled in my router and no firewall present on PC or router. I am also using a Dynamic DNS to access my router's IP from other machines using a domain name. Using port #33333

Server Class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread
{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;

   public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
            serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to "
                  + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in =
                  new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream out =
                 new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
              + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            server.close();
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
         {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
            break;
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int port = 33333;
      try
      {
         Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GreetingClient
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      InetAddress ip;
      String serverName;
      int port = 33333;
      try
      {
         ip = InetAddress.getByName("myserver.dyndns.co.za");
         serverName = ip.getHostAddress();
         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                             + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to "
                      + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out =
                       new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from "
                      + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Things I have noticed:

- When i run the server and use a site such as Canyouseeme.org to check if my port is opened, i get a success and the server throws an exception as coded.
- When i run the server and client from the same PC the client doesn't connect and crashes giving a connection timed out error. the same occurs when i try from another pc.

btw i have changed the name of the domain to ensure some security. "myserver.dyndns.co.za" is made up. but the domain i use is very similar.

I need to know where I am going wrong and why i cannot connect to the server.

I also know that connecting via localhost will solve my problem however that will work only to computers on my network. I am more concerned about getting a machine from anywhere in the world to connect, thus the need for dynamic dns and port forwarding.

My first post so I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: in the client code, does System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName
                                 + " on port " + port);  print out what you are expecting it to print out when?

Comment: Eliminate what you can.  Run the server AND THE CLIENT on the same machine.  Let the client connect to `localhost`, not to `myserver.dyndns.co.za`.  If that works, then we know that at least your code works

Comment: On an unrelated note, this is a VERY well-asked question for your first post.  Well done.

Comment: This is going to be a routing issue. Many consumer routers won't route a connection from an internal NAT address to the public (external) IP and back in via port forwarding. Connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 with the client instead and it should work fine.

Comment: You won't get a SocketTimeoutException unless you set a read timeout with Socket.setSoTimeout().

Comment: @sunrize920 That piece of code is to make sure the domain name I give relates to my ip address. serverName contains the ip address. 
e.g Connecting to 41.212.23.43 on port 33333

Comment: @RussellUhl I have done that. read the the first paragraph again. The code works when using localhost as the host.

Comment: @BrianRoach So what you are suggesting is that I run the client on a pc that is not behind my router. a pc that has a different internet conenction to mine to test that a connection through the internet will work?

Comment: @JesseRyan Bah so you did.  Apologies.  I reread your post specifically to make sure I wasn't suggesting something you already tried, and I missed the very thing I was looking for!

Comment: @JesseRyan: and yes, I believe that is what Brian is suggesting.  Routers use NAT, which essentially means it dynamically maps ports from behind the router so that data can reach the rest of the internet...

Comment: @JesseRyan: ...When you start the client from behind the router, it is going out through port X, bouncing around the net a bit, then coming back to your router ON PORT X, which is already taken by your outgoing traffic.  Either A: run the client on a different network, or B: try the INTERNAL ip address of the server (from behind the router).  Essentially, make sure the data flow is only going through the router a maximum of 1 time.

Comment: @RussellUhl That makes sense. Okay will try that out. But how would I go about instantiating a socket that uses ip address 10.0.0.2 (my router) ... other than that, will setup a pc to use my phone's mobile network and see if i can get two machines to communicate... Thank you

Comment: @jesseryan: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question "How would I go about instantianting a socket that uses ip address...".  Are you asking how you would connect to the server when it is behind the router?

Comment: @RussellUhl According to what you say. this should work if change the outgoing and incoming ports... Will test and reply

Comment: what i meant was that i'm not sure how to create a socket that uses a set ip address. You need a host name when creating a Socket or use a InetAddress and both don't have methods to set the IP address

Comment: @JesseRyan: Ah.  In java, you still use the getByName method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String).  So it would be `ip = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.2");`  Remember though, that's your router's internal ip address, not its external address (not the address the internet uses)

Comment: @RussellUhl I did that // InetAddress.getByName.... and i got a connection refused error

Comment: well like i said, that is your router's internal ip...not your server.  I assume your server is behind your router.  IF you client is inside the router with the server, use the server's IP address.  If the client is OUTSIDE the router, use the router's EXTERNAL IP address, and make sure that the router knows to forward traffic on port 33333 to your server's ip address.

Comment: ahh i get it now. Sorry, I had mixed up the Server and Router ip's. That makes much more sense. And when tested works perfectly. Now i will test from outside the network.

Comment: Okay so final tests with a machine from outside the network works as expected. This was a routing problem. Thanks to all for your assistance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.